# Access vi history

Tags: ssl, vi

I just accidentally pasted a $200 SSL certificate in the private key file and saved in vi. The private key is now lost. I know I yanked the existing data before replacing it and saving. Is it possible to retrieve this data somehow? I think no, but I figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 1):

- If your `vi` session is still running, and you *haven't* written your file yet, just do [esc]`:q!` and you should be back to your original file.
- Or just hit `p` to paste the stuff you yanked previously.
- You *might* have an `id.rsa~` file hanging around. If so, that is your backup file.
- It sounds like you've already written your file, so you are probably out of luck. Can you generate a new keypair and ask your cert vendor to re-issue the cert?
- In the future, you might want to look into setting the `backup` [option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html) in vim. This used to be a default setting in Linux distributions back in the day, but it definitely isn't the default on my mac now.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't quit vi, you can just 'p'.. no?

Comment: Sounds like the OP pasted the cert over the private key, so the key probably isn't in his paste buffer.

Comment: "yanked the existing data before replacing it"

Answer (score 1):

If you yanked the data before you overwrote it, it probably should still be accessible using registers (`:help registers`):

```
:registers
```

will show you the contents of all registers.

If you find the lost text, it can be yanked by using the number displayed at the beginning of the line, e.g. by issuing `"3p` in normal mode.

**UPDATE**: The question was about vi, not vim, right? Then the command registers might not exist; I think the yank registers 0-9 are a vim extension.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose you have backups set do you ([doc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27backup%27))? If not, can't you do `u`?